# ImageResizer AzureReader2 breaks after update

Tags: imageresizer

We upgraded ImageResizer and the AzureReader2 to version 4.0.5, and it seems to have broke the ability to serve images from Azure. Particularly the prefix does not seem to be mapping to a virtual folder.

So given the following configuration :

```
<add name="AzureReader2" connectionString="workedb4" endpoint="workedb4" vpp="true" prefix="~/cloud" />
```

I get 404's for all images with a detailed error like :

[image: error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turn out, when i upgraded, the nuget deleted the references to the AzureReader2 from the project.

After reinstalling the nuget package, the binding redirects to the microsoft azure libraries started giving a yellow screen.

In the end I uninstalled AzureReader2 again, uninstalled all its dependencies, and then deleted all the binding redirects for those dependencies in the web.config, and reinstalled, and it all seems to work